# Can the MAC address of the USB stick broadband connection be traced together with the IP address?

Tags: ip, network-adapter, privacy, broadband, mobile-broadband

Can the MAC address of the USB stick broadband connection be traced together with the IP address?

Also, the mac address of the broadband stick used, computer or network card inside the laptop, etc.?

Comment: In general, MAC addresses are only visible to devices on the same LAN.

Comment: What if directly connected to the internet (through the ISP)?

Comment: It's still only visible on the LAN connecting your PC to the ISP. If you're on a cable modem, it will only be visible to the devices on the same cable node.

Comment: @ Barmar : Thanks for your reply. Does that mean websites have no ways of seeing the MAC addresses of their site visitors? But only their IP addresses?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So there is no way of tracing someone if he uses his own connection, then switch to an anonymous connection even though it is coming from the same source/computer/laptop?

Comment: Not through normal HTTP applications or underlying TCP/IP protocols. Flash applications or native Windows/Unix applications get get details about the PC and send them to the server.

Comment: Where can I find references regarding how to implement that? How can I know if two instances of site visits on my Website is actually coming from the same source/person?